# Write a byte to a file in C

Tags: c, byte, fwrite, fread, unsigned-integer

I have a byte declared as `unsigned int 0b11010101`how can I write this to a binary file as 1 byte? I know fwrite takes type `const void *`as a buffer but I don't know how to write my byte if it's represented as an unsigned int.

Comment: Send a pointer to it...

Comment: `0b11010101` isn't valid C. Are you using gcc by any chance?

Comment: yes I'm using gcc and it compiles fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps like this, you better not write one byte of an `int` because of endianness. Convert to `unsigned char` first.

```
unsigned int intval = 0b11010101;       // assuming compiler likes it
unsigned char charval = intval;
fwrite (&charval, 1, 1, stream);
```

Comment: I have used **fprintf()** to write binary, files.                                      **unsigned int val=0b11010101;…………fopen(…);…………fprintf(fp,"%c",val);** will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a single byte to a file using [fputc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fputc).

Example:

```c
unsigned int val = 0b11010101;
fputc(val, stream);
```

Tested using:

```sh
~ $ cc -Wall -o test test.c
~ $ ./test | xxd
00000000: d5                                       .
```